# Retornar valor em string com firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

No Android Studio tenho o seguinte código no MainActivity

```
package br.alan.com.firebaseapp;

import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Referencia a banco de dados do site do firebase
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    //Referencia o nome do banco de dados
    public DatabaseReference usuarioReferencia = databaseReference;
    private TextView texto;
    private Button botaoValor;
    private EditText valor;


    @Override
    public View findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
        return super.findViewById(id);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        botaoValor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoId);
        valor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.valorId);



        botaoValor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String valorDigitado = valor.getText().toString();

                usuarioReferencia.child(valorDigitado).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            texto.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                        }else{
                            texto.setText("Não existe!");
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        texto.setText("Dados não encontrado!");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

No firabase tenho os valores

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando executo o emulador do AndroidStudio tenho o seguinte dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faço para formatar essa string, tirar esse { } que parece que está retornando um json. Quando eu coloco `texto.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());` no código está retornando esses dados. Gostaria de saber como retornar sem {} e saber manipular esses dados.

Comment: pode ser meio besta a pergunta, mas vc consegue acessar o objeto: dataSnapshot.pais.getValue().toString()?

Comment: Caso o objeto vem totalmente em string vc pode usar esse Mavem do google que converte JSON string em Objeto: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson

Comment: blz, irei verificar, só consigo retornar em string quando eu pego um dados depois de Alan. Por exemplo utilizando esse codigo usuarioReferencia.child("Alan").child("pais"), ai ele retorna em string. Mas queria pegar um conjunto de dados. Mas se não der certo irei utilizar aprender o parse ou heroku.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que a forma mais indicada para uma futura adaptação do código seria criar uma classe que instancia estes dados, no caso uma classe chamada *User*:

```html
public class User {

    public String name;
    public String email;

    public User() {
    
    }

    public User(String name, String email) {
        this.name= name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

Aqui o código retorna a classe que você quer:

```html
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    
    }
};
```

Aqui você já tem instância de usuário com os dados disponíveis, então é só trabalhar com estes dados:

```html
user.getName(); //Retorna o nome
```